# Database SQL Executor (legacy) 0:2211 Execute failed: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: database, knime

Node `DB SQL Executor (legacy)` gives for one worker this error. I can not reproduce this error in any way. We have the exact same workflow, we have the same access to the same DB and we are on the same connection. I'm sorry I'm not providing a lot of information here but asking maybe perhaps there could be an obvious thing that I'm missing. Since I don't have this error it means the code is working fine, something is wrong on his side, could it be knime extensions or user rights? For example he is missing some extensions that I have but I can't imagine why an extension would be the problem, he should, not sure but should have same rights as well.

> ERROR Database SQL Executor (legacy) 0:2211     Execute failed: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_01_articles_c'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'DB.01_articles_c'. The duplicate key value is (c, 1142192).

Comment: Are you saying you have same workflows and he gets error while your runs without problems? Also does this mean you are inserting exact data into same database table?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes the exact same copy of workflow and exact same data.

Comment: Did he checked the input of the executor? Does it contain the key multiple times? Did he rerun the node that deletes/truncates the table (I assume you did)?

Comment: Found out. For no reason what so ever he F-ed up the data. I assumed it would be something easy but knowing he's our chief analyst I didn't argue too much. Thanks for the tips all.